# multiple stacked bar charts on a panel (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, stacked-chart

my dataframe looks like this:

```
time Country  Share1 Share2 Share3 Share4
1990  A       10     30     50     10
1991  A       20     70     5      5
1992  A       15     15     50     20
1990  B       40     10     15     35
1991  B       70     10     10     10
```

essentially, I would like to create stacked bar charts for each country over time.

a code like:

```
for values in df.country:
    values.bar(share*, over=year, stacked=True)
```

...that code won't work, but that's the gist of what I want to do. I want to loop over every country (because I have 200 countries) rather than type them in one by one.  Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't too bad to accomplish once you understand what the plotting methods you can call from a `DataFrame` object use for the axes and data.  The x-axis will be the index of the data frame and each column represents a series (each series has one value per x-value).  Assuming your data frame is called `df`:

```
# set the values for the x-axis that we want to plot,
# in this case the time values in years
df.set_index(['time'], inplace=True)

# iterate through the list of countries, and create a plot
for country in df.Country.unique():
    # .plot.bar makes bar charts
    ax = df[df.Country==country].plot.bar(stacked=True)
    # make room for the legend, and sets in the upper right corner
    ax.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim()[0],ax.get_xlim()[1]+1)
    ax.legend(loc='upper right')
    # add the country name to the top of the chart.
    ax.set_title(country)
```

You can save the image file on each iteration.

[image]

Comment: this worked perfectly, thank you. I added a few lines of code: `ax.legend_.remove()` to remove the legend.
`plt.savefig(country+'.png')` to save the country names. and  `plt.close('all')` to close plots because it takes up memory